# How to make a grid out of a vector

Tags: vector, grid

I have a vector, let us call it x.

I want to make a grid of points between 1 and a variable, let us call the variable xm.

How can I make a grid between 1 and xm of the vector (x) with total number of points (nump), so that the points are evenly spaced between 1 and xm?

Does something like this work:

```
  for (int i=0;i<nump;i++)
  {
    double s = (xm - 1.0)/nump;
    x[i]= 1.0 + i*s;
  }
```

Comment: What code have you tried in order to make this grid?

Comment: What I have so far is:
for (int i=0;i<nump;i++) [i+1] = x[0]
but clearly this is not complete. just trying to wrap my head around how to make the grid

Comment: I don't think `[i+1] = x[0]` is a proper statement. What comes before `[i+1]`?

Comment: I wrote what comes before it - again, I could be doing it wrong. Just trying to get some help in making a grid, I have not made one before